# Perl how to stop regex pattern match when another pattern match occurs?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a pattern matcher code as like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open(HTML,"<source.html");
my $html = do {local $/; <HTML>};
$html =~ s/\n\ *//g;
while ($html=~m/<OPTION [^>]*>\D*([^<]+)/g){
    print $1;
    print "\n";
}
close(HTML)
```

I want to do it until the file however I want to stop and break while loop it it sees any character that matches with a pattern that start with:

```
</S
```

How can I do that with Perl?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exit from a loop , you should use the last command:

```
last if ( $pattern ~= /^<\/S/ );
```

Comment: My problem is that: my first regex checker removes the words that inludes "</S" so I should modify my code with doing something with my pattern at while loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
( my $to_search = $html ) =~ s{</S.*}{}s;
while ($to_search =~ m{<OPTION [^>]*>\D*([^<]+)}g) {
    print("$1\n");
}
```